# Jquery on resize apply parent width to child

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, resize

How can I apply width of the `li` to the `a` ? This should happen on resize.
So the `a` always have the `li` width.

http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/5/

```
var parentWidth = $('ul li').parent().width();
var $window = $(window);
$window.resize(function resize() {
    $('ul li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).closest('a').length == 1) {
            parentWidth = $(this).closest('a').css('width').replace('px', '');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: make anchor display block, don't need width 100% http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/4/

Comment: @Huangism thanks but I'd like to apply to the anchor the with of the li with jquery.

Comment: you can always set the css prop of display on the anchor to block using jquery :) Also closest is used to find parents of the current element, to find children, use .find() http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.resize(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function () {
        var parentWidth = $(this).width();
        if ($(this).find('a').length) {
            $(this).find('a').width(parentWidth)
        }
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

If your anchor tags have a css property of "block" that *should* make the anchor element take the width of it's parent container. In this case, it is the "li" - which by default, is a block-level element.

If you are floating your list elements, give your "li" elements a width (using css). Then like you have now you can use "inline-block" to give your anchor tags a width (and/or height).

Comment: please have a look my new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/5/ it's a metter of jquery not css.

Comment: Unless you absolutely need it, I would remove:
"position: absolute;"
then and add:
"display: block;"

Answer (score 1):

as dragonslovetaco's has stated, you really should use CSS for this - check your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/6/

Applying position:relative to the list items + having width:inherit on the a's will cause them to copy width.

`a{background:red;display:inline-block; width:inherit;}
    li{position:relative; width:100%;}`